# cannot find openjdk-11 for RHEL7

Tags: java, openjdk, rhel-7

I have been trying to install java-11-openjdk-devel required for NetApp AIUM 9.6 on a RHEL 7.5 server.

As per Redhat developer portal "https://developers.redhat.com/openjdk-install/#"
package could be found in rhel-7-server-optional-rpms

However, upon running "yum install java-11-openjdk-devel", package is not found

***Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
rhel-7-server-extras-rpms | 2.0 kB 00:00:00
rhel-7-server-optional-rpms | 2.0 kB 00:00:00
rhel-7-server-rh-common-rpms | 2.1 kB 00:00:00
rhel-7-server-rpms | 2.0 kB 00:00:00
No package java-11-openjdk-devel available.
Error: Nothing to do***

I installed opnjdk11 manually, updated alternatives but still the NetAppp installer fails as I suppose it is trying to look for the repository with jdk11.

Any suggestions!!